# Power query (powerbi) transforming panel data (cross-sectional-temporal data) into a cross-sectional structure with added temporal columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am working in powerbi and I have a problem in the power query editor. My source table contains cross-sectional-temporal data with both cross-sectional and temporal primary keys (2 identifiers):

```
primary_key    time_year  data_feature_A
    1             2019         A
    1             2020         C
    1             2021         L
    1             2022         B
    2             2019         K
    2             2020         H
    2             2021         M
    2             2022         D
    3             2019         A
    3             2020         F
    3             2021         X
    3             2022         Y
    4             2019         Y
    4             2020         D
    4             2021         M
    4             2022         H
```

At the end of the procedure, the table should have the following structure:

```
primary_key   2019     2020     2021     2022
    1           A        C        L        B
    2           K        H        M        D
    3           A        F        X        Y
    4           Y        D        M        H
```

How do I do this most efficiently in Power Query? I would like to run such a procedure on a very big data set (original data).

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, just pivot the data

click select the time_year column

transform...pivot column...

values column:data_feature_a

advanced options...dont aggregate

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"time_year", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"time_year", type text}}, "en-US")[time_year]), "time_year", "data_feature_A")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```